# Does Kingfisher support WebP on iOS 14+?

Tags: ios, image, caching, webp, kingfisher

I’m getting mixed signals as [the wiki says](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#creating-your-own-processor):

> `WebpFramework` is an external framework you may use to parse WebP data. Currently, Kingfisher does not support WebP image out of the box.

But then there’s [this comment](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1778#issuecomment-901601660) from the author saying:

> This is a WebP image and only built-in supported from iOS 14.

Which also points to [the FAQ where it says](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/FAQ#can-i-load-some-special-image-format-like-webp):

> Can I load some special image format like WebP?
>
> Yes, but it is not built-in supported in Kingfisher. You may need to implement your own `ImageProcessor` and `CacheSerializer`. It is also already done by some other libraries, for example, [KingfisherWebP](https://github.com/yeatse/KingfisherWebP). For more discussion on this topic, search for "webp" in the issues.

It’s not clear to me whether [iOS 14 built-in support](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551599-webp) is automatically “absorbed" into Kingfisher or not, and I’m confused as to why the wiki nor the FAQ mention this.

I’d prefer to avoid using KingfisherWebP since it doesn’t seem very active and based on [this comment](https://github.com/yeatse/KingfisherWebP/issues/59#issuecomment-948205320) from the author they’re not yet taking advantage of the iOS 14 support?

> I also noticed that from iOS 14 webp format has a built-in support. We're planning to implement this feature to reduce the memory footprint in iOS 14 devices.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes: [Kingfisher supports WebP on iOS 14+](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/2072#issuecomment-1533193852) and [the FAQ has been updated with this info](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/FAQ#can-i-load-some-special-image-format-like-webp).